# Locate elements in list

Tags: list, f#

I built a simple function that tells me where a given element is actually in a list. The first position is 0:

```
let rec foo79 =
fun k l ->
    match k, l with
    | k, []         ->  failwith "What you are lookig for is not here"
    | k, (x::xs)    ->  if      x = k   then    0
                        else    1 + foo79 k xs
```

It is simple and works (even so, every suggestion to improve it is welcome!).

What I failed to do, with this function, is to make it tell me the **positions** of `x`, in the case that `x` occurs **multiple** times in the list. 
My attemps so far do not even get close to a solution. I am actually posting it just to make you an example of the approach I am pursuing.

```
let rec foo79b =
fun k l ->
    match k, l with
    | k, []         ->  failwith "What you are lookig for is not here"
    | k, (x::xs)    ->  if      x = k   &   (x::xs) then    1 + foo79b k xs
                        elif    x = k   &   []      then    0
                        else    1 + foo79b k xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function will need to return a list of positions, so you can use an accumulator for the resulting list. At the same time you can use another auxiliary parameter to tread the index instead of having to sum at the call site:

```
let findAllPos elem lst = 
    let rec foo79 =
        fun k l i acc ->
            match k, l with
            | k, []      -> acc
            | k, (x::xs) -> if x = k then foo79 k xs (i+1) (i::acc)
                            else          foo79 k xs (i+1)     acc
    foo79 elem lst 0 []
```

This way it becomes simpler and more importantly makes your solution [tail recursive](https://www.google.com/search?q=tail+recursive&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIE761IE761&oq=tail+recursive&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2440j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If you don't believe me try calling your first function like this `foo79 400000 [0..400000]` then try the one I'm proposing `findAllPos 400000 [0..400000]`.

Comment: I did not think to create a list as output. Thanks for the precious suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
let positions (x: 'a) (xs: 'a seq) : int seq =
    xs
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i y -> if y = x then Some i else None)
    |> Seq.choose id

// [0; 0; 2; 3; 4; 0; 6] |> positions 0;;
// val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 1; 5]
```

Works with sequences too.

This one only works with lists (not sequences) and could be quite slow:

```
let positions' (x: 'a) (xs: 'a list) : int list =
    [0..(Seq.length xs - 1)]
    |> List.filter (fun i -> xs.[i] = x)

// [0; 0; 2; 3; 4; 0; 6] |> positions' 0;;
// val it : int list = [0; 1; 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your examples!